# How use IInterceptor in Castle.DynamicProxy?

Tags: c#, interceptor, castle-dynamicproxy, dynamic-proxy, interception

I wrote an example like this

**Simple Calculator class :**

```
public class Calculator
{
    public int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

**implemented "IInterceptor" that provided by DynamicProxy**

```
 [Serializable]
public abstract class Interceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        ExecuteBefore(invocation);
        invocation.Proceed();
        ExecuteAfter(invocation);

    }
    protected abstract void ExecuteAfter(IInvocation invocation);
    protected abstract void ExecuteBefore(IInvocation invocation);
}
```

**Created an Interceptor class and inherited from "Interceptor" class**

```
    public class CalculatorInterceptor : Interceptor
{
    protected override void ExecuteBefore(Castle.DynamicProxy.IInvocation invocation)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start");
    }

    protected override void ExecuteAfter(Castle.DynamicProxy.IInvocation invocation)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("End");
    }
}
```

but when I used it NOT working !!!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProxyGenerator generator = new ProxyGenerator();
        Calculator c = generator.CreateClassProxy<Calculator>(new CalculatorInterceptor());
        var r = c.Add(11, 22);
        Console.WriteLine(r);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

I excepted to see something like this :

```
START
33
END
```

but only show

```
33
```

How I can correct it ?!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try to make the method `Add` virtual.

```
public class Calculator
{
    public virtual int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

The proxy generator creates a new class inheriting `Calculator`. Thus, the method `Add` gets an override to make interception possible.

Comment: yes, seems ok but a question the result is START
END 33 how I can set Before & After in correct way and see result like this START 33 END , Can I correct this in Interceptor class for correct methods call ??!!!

Comment: @user3153878 the interceptor executes right before and after the `Add` call, but you write the result after that to the console (execute before -> execute Add -> execute after -> write result). If you make the console call within the `Add` method, you should get the desired result.

Answer (score 14):

The other option is to make an ICalculator interface

```
public interface ICalculator
{
   int Add(int a, int b);
}
```

and inherit your class from this interface

```
public class Calculator : ICalculator
{
    public int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Your dynamic proxy would then use the *CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget* method

```
var proxyGenerator = new ProxyGenerator();

ICalculator calculator = new Calculator()

var proxy = proxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget(
    calculator,
    ProxyGenerationOptions.Default,
    new CalculatorInterceptor());

Console.WriteLine(proxy.Add(1, 2));
```

This gets rid of the virtual from your Calculator class, which in my opinion is bad design unless you have reason to override the method in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the correct overload and pass in both the target object  and the interceptor you wish to use. Method should look something like this:

```
var proxy = generator.CreateClassProxy<Calculator>(new Calculator(), new CalculatorInterceptor() );
```